How to use the Keychain API from Swift without memory leak?
In a SwiftUI application for macOS I'm trying to keep a password in the default keychain. There is no shortage of example code and wrappers for the arguably clunky Core Foundation API. They all essentially use the same pattern to retrieve a password from the keychain – somehow like this:
func getPassword(forService service: String) throws -> String? {
    let query = [
        kSecClass:        kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrService:  service,
        kSecMatchLimit:   kSecMatchLimitOne,
        kSecReturnData:   true
    ] as NSDictionary
    var result: CFTypeRef?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result)
    if status == errSecItemNotFound {
        return nil
    }
    if status != errSecSuccess {
        throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: Int(status))
    }
    guard let data = result as? Data else { return nil }
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}

The code above works, but it also leaks memory every time it's is called. The leak is not shown in Instruments but it's obvious when you loop over the function above. I guess the clue is in the name of the function SecItemCopyMatching. It copies the result, but then the result is not freed.
This issue has been documented, for example on the Apple forums here, but I can't seem to find any solution.
I've tried to free the memory manually, along the lines of what's proposed in this answer (for a different problem) but that results in a crash.
Any ideas on how to use SecItemCopyMatching correctly from Swift? I'm highlighting the use from Swift here because it seems that in Objective-C you might be able to call CFRelease on the returned result, as mentioned in the question suggested by @PtitXav.

Does this answer your question? SecItemCopyMatching memory leaking

In my KeychainClass
based entirely on https://www.advancedswift.com/secure-private-data-keychain-swift/
I used var result: AnyObject? and
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result).
Note, haven't tested it for memory leaks.

@PtitXav The question you linked is for Objective-C. The answer suggests to call CFRelease on the result, and it suggests a code change to make that possible. It doesn't seem possible to call CFRelease from Swift. So, unfortunately, that doesn't help.

When calling SecItemCopyMatching(_:_:) you'r are passing in a value of type CFTypeRef ? for the result parameter.  You need to apply manual ref-counting there - which you didn't. You may test again using instead var result: AnyObject? for the result - which should apply ARC.

@CouchDeveloper Interesting idea. Unfortunately, changing the type to AnyObject? doesn't make any difference. The leak is still there. Manually freeing the object using Unmanaged.passUnretained(result).release() results in a crash. The object is released too often which I confirmed using the Zombie Objects diagnostics.

This looks more and more like a bug in an Apple library. Interestingly, there are different Keychain implementations on macOS and iOS (see reply by the Apple engineer here), which, if the bug isn't present in iOS, would explain why this is not more widely discussed.

May be this will help you.

Erik, I need to correct myself:  Swift already manages CFTypeRef types - actually CFTypeRef  is a typealias for AnyObject.
